# Get rid of X in slds-modal in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, modal

I've been trying to make my own custom modal (based on the lightning design for modals) However I seem to be running into some issues in getting rid of the floating X when the modal shows up.
[image]

I removed the line of code which adds it, but for some reason it's still showing, and I was wondering if there was some other place where theres some kind of css property that makes that dsplayed. Here's the html for the modal

```
<template>
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <h1 class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:service_crew_member" size="medium" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-icon> 
                Assign Vendor 
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning-combobox
                label="Vendor Assigned"
                value={selectedVendor}
                options={vendors}
                field-level-help="Select the vendor to assign the asset to."
                onchange={handleVendorChange}
            ></lightning-combobox>
            <lightning-combobox
                label="Vendor Contact"
                value={selectedContact}
                options={contacts}
                field-level-help="Select the contact at the vendor to assign the asset to."
                onchange={handleContactChange}
            ></lightning-combobox>
        </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Cancel" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Assign" onclick={assignVendor} variant="brand"></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```